# Vaadin 8 Binding to a Pojo when using Vaadin Designer

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I am working on a project where the UI is being generated from the Vaadin designer.  I have the html generated and the corresponding .java file.

I extend the java file and binding my data to the view of the design.  The basic code to display my data is working as each field on the form has a corresponding pojo variable.  Now I want to display two fields together on the form much like you would combine first and last name to show a full name.

My pojo has a toString method that returns the two values combined but I can't figure out how to set the label propertyNoName to the value of aPropertyProfile.toString()

```
public class PropertyProfileDesign extends VerticalLayout
{

    private VerticalLayout  propertyProfileHeader;
    private Label           propertyNoName;
    private TextField       propertyMgr;
    private TextField       propertyMgrPhone;
    private TextField       propertyMgrCellular;
    private TextField       propertyMgrHome;
    private TextField       regionalMgr;
    private TextField       regionalMgrPhone;
    private TextField       regionalMgrCellular;
    private TextField       regionalMgrHome;
    private VerticalLayout  propertyProfileBodyFooter;

    public PropertyProfileDesign()
    {
        Design.read( this );
    }

    public VerticalLayout getPropertyProfileHeader()
    {
        return propertyProfileHeader;
    }

    public Label getPropertyNoName()
    {
        return propertyNoName;
    }

    public TextField getPropertyMgr()
    {
        return propertyMgr;
    }

    public TextField getPropertyMgrPhone()
    {
        return propertyMgrPhone;
    }

    public TextField getPropertyMgrCellular()
    {
        return propertyMgrCellular;
    }

    public TextField getPropertyMgrHome()
    {
        return propertyMgrHome;
    }

    public TextField getRegionalMgr()
    {
        return regionalMgr;
    }

    public TextField getRegionalMgrPhone()
    {
        return regionalMgrPhone;
    }

    public TextField getRegionalMgrCellular()
    {
        return regionalMgrCellular;
    }

    public TextField getRegionalMgrHome()
    {
        return regionalMgrHome;
    }

    public VerticalLayout getPropertyProfileBodyFooter()
    {
        return propertyProfileBodyFooter;
    }
}

public class PropertyProfileView extends PropertyProfileDesign
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7454308982717559970L;

    private Binder<PropertyProfile> binder = new Binder<>( PropertyProfile.class );

    public PropertyProfileView()
    {
    }

    public PropertyProfileView( final PropertyProfile aPropertyProfile )
    {
        this();

        binder.bindInstanceFields( this );
        binder.readBean( aPropertyProfile );
        //  How to update the label field propertyNoName with aPropertyProfile.toString()?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the setValue(..) method of Label:

```
propertyNoName.setValue(aPropertyProfile.toString());
```